# Submit button not firing in asp.net after javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, user-interface

I am having a textbox with onpress and onblur event, and the javascript function will format the text to (xx-xxxxx).

```
<input type="text" id="txtnum"  
    onblur="javascript:return myfunc(this)"  
    onkeypress="javascript:return myfunc(this)">

Function myfunc(elem)
{
    If(elem!=null)
    {
        Var str=elem.value;
        If(str.length==2)
        {
            Str=str+"-";
            Return true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter a number say 12345678, its formatted to 12-345678, but the submit button is not fired.

If I just enter numbers the submit button is fired.

I have set causes validation ="false" that too didn't work.

Comment: JS doesn't have an `onpress` function. Are you looking for an event where a user types something

Comment: What submit button?  And what errors are showing in F12 console?

Comment: My bad its onkeypress and on the console it doesnt show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write return statement outside if condition

```
 If(str.length==2)
        {
            Str=str+"-";

        }

Return true;
```